# testing socket communication offline as a simulation

Tags: iphone, sockets, asyncsocket

Whenever having to test my app which basically is some kind of communication via sockets with external devices, the device itself has to be available and connected.

I would like to ask,if there is a way to do the testing offline in some kind of simulation mode?

For instance, redirecting the socket communication to some kind of stored file. And the file itself is a log of a previous session with the real device stored in an appropriate structure. Of course one could only simulate a recorded session, but that would help a lot already.

thanks!

Comment: Why not puting the remote application (server) in the same machine where the client resides? Then, both can communicate locally.

Comment: because there is no remote app, my app communicates with an external hardware device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [`netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/). If you have a record of your "session" in a file, you can use `nc` to "play it back" on a socket with something like:

```
nc -l -p port_number < your_file
```

You can then connect to that port number with `telnet` and you'll see the session data coming in.

(You can do it the other way around too, i.e. have `nc` connect to your app and replay the session.)

Comment: thanks very much. I did some reading...but I am not sure exactly what to install now. Is there any difference between nc / ncat (part of nmap)?

Comment: They're not the same tool. `ncat` seems to have more features. Try both :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know iphone, but having a local client, (or server), app. as a simulator is very common on other platforms.  It's especially useful if the peer app is under development as well - having a simulator often surfaces protocol bugs at both ends, (as well as in the simulator:).

Given an app spec that includes the protocol, but no peer yet, I usually start work on the simulator first - it gives me time to get experience with the protocol in an non-critical, non-deliverable way while the customer is still bolting on changes to the main app UI :)

Rgds,
Martin